# View private Instagram photos through a web browser

Tags: photos, instagram

My [Instagram](http://instagr.am/) account has a set of photos (marked as private) that I want to get access to. I don't currently have access to an IOS device so cannot use the Instagram application to view the photos.

How can I view (and download) these private photos through a web application?

Answer (score 4):

> [Instagre.at](http://instagre.at/) is a great new web app that shows you what’s currently popular on Instagram. Beautiful minimal design and animation blends perfectly with the Instagram theme.

- http://instagre.at/

#### To download your photos from Instagreat

1. sign in with Instagram (bottom-left button)
2. click your name to see your own timeline.
3. Right-click > Save Image to download.

[This is slightly faster/better than web.stagram.com, because webstagram defaults to showing you a smaller thumbnail.]

Comment: Nice interface, also like the intuitive keyboard navigation and "view others using this filter" feature.

Comment: Seemed to keep my photos private - unlike the web.stagram.com service.

Answer (score 3):

http://web.stagram.com/

> Webstagram is an Instagram Web Viewer.

Hope this helps

Comment: I noticed that after I logged in with this service it made all my private photos public through their site (for anyone that knew my username). As such, I'm going to have to accept the instagre.at service as the answer because it didn't automatically make all my photos public.

Comment: Wow, that's really shoddy. You should drop a note to the webstgram team.

Answer (score 1):

[Instagrid](http://instagrid.me/) is another webapp that let's you access your Instagram photos on the web. I think because you log into Instagrid, users who know your Instagrid URL can see all of your photos, whether or not your account it set to private. Instagrid doesn't have a directory listing, so I think the only people who can access your feed is those you give the URL to. So, even if my account was set to private, you would (and can) see all of my photos there - for example: http://instagrid.me/jaredharley/.

From Instagram's FAQ:

> **Who can see my photos?**
>
> All photos are public by default which means they are visible to anyone using Instagram or on the instagr.am website. If you choose to make your account private, then only people who follow you on Instagram will be able to see your photos.

I think being able to see an Instagram user's photos through another website is a limitation of the Instagram API - the webapp has no idea if someone has their account set to private or not. If it was, you'd have to have the possible viewer log in to Instagram at the webapp, then check and see whether the user is allowed to see your Instagram feed.

In either case, Instagrid does give you the ability to view the images full-sized and download them.